# Update a tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interface

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Tkinter for building a window.
In this window I've a lot of scales and check buttons and they read and modify a txt file.

Is it possible to automatically update their value every x seconds?

For example, every 5 seconds read the txt file and update every variable and every value of the window?

Comment: Take a look at the `.after` method

Comment: Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) of the `.after()` widget method. It can be used to call a function after a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I'll take a look right now and I'll let you know...

Comment: [examples with after which update current time](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after)